# Content is getting truncated when rendered as PDF

Tags: visualforce, controller, aura

I have a query like i am generating a pdf file in which all the content notes will be displayed.I found an issue like content of contentnotes is getting truncated when pdf file is generated.Please let me know why the content is getting truncated.....i converted the content and then only i am displaying on pdf page.is there any restriction for content to display?

I followed the below blog and displaying the content of contentnotes on vf page......but its getting truncated.Full content is not displaying.

[Trying to show the content field (blob) from contentNote in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177958/trying-to-show-the-content-field-blob-from-contentnote-in-visualforce)

From my debugging i found like that whole content is getting truncated only for below scenerios:

1. Working scenerio:

- when i login as user1 and create the case.
- post that when i login as user2 and add notes to the created case(by user1) and
- if i generate the pdf content then the content in notes is not getting truncated.

2. Failing scenerio:

- when i login as user1 and creates the case and add notes
- then if i generate pdf with the related notes then the content of the notes is getting truncated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have added additional information too

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  You'll get more help by showing screenshots of the non-truncated vs truncated use case along with the minimum amount of apex/vf to illustrate the issue - no code dumps please